# Как сделать блок ссылкой?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ссылки

Заказчику срочно понадобилось, чтобы блок стал ссылкой, но внутри этого блока есть и куча разметки, в том числе, и самостоятельных тегов `<a>`. В результате, если обернуть весь блок этим тегом, браузер просто выкинет его оттуда, и будет отдельно ссылка и отдельно блок. Каким образом можно сделать блок со сложной разметкой ссылкой, чтобы не поссорить сайт с поисковыми системами?

Comment: Скиньте код, чтобы понять вашу ситуацию еще лучше.

Comment: Через `addEventListener();` отслеживать через `target` по клику или почему там нужно...

Comment: Какое же должно быть у человека больное воображение, чтобы целый блок, да еще и с другими ссылками, сделать ссылкой))))  Не завидую тебе

Comment: @Air Да это геморно, но это не самые "извращенные эстетические пожелания" от заказчика. Это в принципе решаемая проблема.

Comment: @Air, спасибо за понимание. К сожалению, это не самая большая из проблем.

Comment: @nup А какая ж тогда "самая"?

Comment: @Air, самая большая проблема - в общем подходе, с неосмысленными задачами, большинство из которых после извращенного выполнения отменяются: "Верни как было".

Comment: Самодур))))))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.outer{
  position:relative;
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
}
.direct-link {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  background: red;
}
.all-block-link {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="google.com" class="direct-link">link</a>
    </div>
    <a href="some-other-link.com" class="all-block-link">link</a>
</div>
```

Попробуй сделать следующее

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
$("#block").click(function(){ location.href="нужный url" }); 
$("#block a").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation()});
```